# SQL in Python (How to store dynamic data?)

Tags: python, sql

I'm creating a little script in Python to scrap from a site and store text and values in a sql database (I'm really a beginner on Python and sql).

A part of my code is:

```
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(Match_Time TEXT, Team_1 TEXT, Team_2 TEXT, Tournament TEXT)')

create_table()

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO matches(Match_Time, Team_1, Team_2) VALUES (?, ?)",
        (e.text.strip(), e.text.strip(), e.text.strip()))
    conn.commit()

table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table[class='odds-data']")

for e in table:
   if e.text is not "" and e.text.strip():
      print e.text.strip()
      data_entry() # to store in sql
```

The output from the site for example is the following:

```
12.00

Belgium

1.862

Over 2

1.813

Under 2

2.120

Sweden

5.250

***************

06.00

Poland

2.679

Over 2

2.320

Under 2

1.675

Switzerland

3.240
```

'*******' means another match

What I would like to do is to store the values and text from that output in a way that assign for every row in the output the correct column in sql.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do, any suggestion?

Thanks to everyone for the help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should pass the data you want to insert to the `data_entry` function as parameters: `def data_entry(time, team1, team2): ...` and in your loop call it `data_entry(e.text.strip(), 'team1', 'team2')` . Also the `VALUES (?, ?)` part of the query only gets 2 values, should be `VALUES (?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... So how should be my code? sorry I don't know how to adjust my code based on what you said